# AnchroPoint x:0, y:0 not working with equation

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit, anchorpoint

I am trying to build a Breakout game where I set the bricks exactly how I want them for each level using 1 SKSpriteNode. It all works, as in they spawn but way off screen to the bottom left. I am using the following line right at the start of didMove(to view: SKView):

```
scene?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
```

And the code I use for spawning the bricks is:

```
//MARK: Brick Layout Config
let widthOfTiles = 7
let heightOfTiles = 3

let widthPoints = 50
let heightPoints = 20

// Different tile arrangements (e.g. 7 tiles wide, 3 high, 7*3 = 21 total tiles)
var brickArray = [false,  true, false,  true, false,  true, false,
                  false,  true,  true,  true, false,  true, false,
                  false,  true, false,  true, false,  true, false] // Says 'HI' using tiles

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //MARK: Brick
    for tile in 0..<brickArray.count {
        if brickArray[tile] == true {

            let brick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red_brick")

            brick.position = CGPoint(x: (tile % widthOfTiles) * (widthPoints) - (widthOfTiles / 2 * (widthPoints)),
                                     y: ((tile - (tile % widthOfTiles)) / widthOfTiles) * (heightPoints) - (heightOfTiles / 2 * (heightPoints)))
            brick.size = CGSize(width: widthPoints, height: heightPoints)
            brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: brick.frame.size)
            brick.physicsBody?.friction = 0
            brick.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            brick.physicsBody?.friction = 0
            brick.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
            brick.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = brickCategory
            self.addChild(brick)
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me get this to be in the center of the scene. Maybe someone can help me figure this out. Maths is a bad weak point of mine and while I think I got the equation right for the spawning, the position is way off.

If I am missing something that you need to see please let me know.

Comment: Why do you want the anchor at 0,0?  Does the default of 0.5,0.5 not work for a particular animation?  If 0,0 is needed you will have to adjust the position to be positioned where you want. There are questions that show this as the adjustment needed

Comment: I am just so used to 0,0. And can't get my head around 0,5

Comment: Unless this is animation specific don’t change the anchor point. Otherwise you are going to get different Visual representation of your position.

Comment: I see, thanks, can you put that as an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: btw, I don't use any kind of .sks, I program everything in code only. So the default for that is 0.0

Comment: I’m sorry but the anchor point default value is 0.5. You may be talking about origin

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode/1519877-anchorpoint

Comment: Ok so what I got is this if I remove all anchorpoint code tgat i set then the anchorpoint goes to 0.0. I know the default for .sks files is 0.5 but since I don’t use those I deleted both the GameScene.sks and ActionScebe.sks and in the GameViewController i have it as let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size) and anchorpoint seems to be at 0.0 unless I set the GameScene.swift file to scene?.anchorpoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

Comment: You dont ever take the scene width and height into consideration with your math, so why would it ever center?

Comment: If you take the screen size/2 and subtract the perimeter of your tiles /2, that will center your block. So `scene.width / 2 - (widthPoints * widthOfTiles) / 2 ` is your starting position, then add on the tile offset position to this number ( or use another SKNode to offset for you)

Comment: Thanks can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need an animation that depends on the anchor point I would not set it and leave it at its default value or it will change the visual representation of the position of the layer.